# PHP check if email already exist

Tags: php

Im trying to check if email already exist in my DB (in my registration form), but I want in the same IF statement to check if its email actually.

I wrote this code, but I still can register with email address that already exist in the DB. What am I doing wrong?

```
function CheckEmail()
{
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='" . $email . "'");
     $a = mysql_num_rows($query);
     if ((!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) OR ($a >= 1))
     {
         echo "Your email is not valid or already exists!";
         echo $a;
     }
     else
     {
         return true;      
     }
}
```

Comment: At first..do not use mysql..(msqli is the way.)

Comment: It's impossible to tell without more context.  Perhaps you need to return false in your if() statement?  However the logic seems correct assuming the code not included here is checking for CheckEmail === true

Comment: The problem is in your conditional statement

Comment: `Return false;` in your `If` staement

Comment: BTW, if your email is not valid, it doesn't make sense to check if it also already exists

Comment: Check if the email is valid BEFORE you use it in a SQL Query and use LIMIT 1 to optimize your script.

Comment: There're many ways in which this code can fail. Es: with `$email="valid'email@abc.de";` your query is corrupted and `mysql_num_rows` will return "false". But "false" is NOT `>=1`, so your function give you true. This is just one example of situation where things could go wrong. Another will be with`$email="[spacehere]mail_already_exist@abc.de";`

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `UNIQUE`  constraint on your email column, this way you'll get a MySQL error when you try to insert a duplicated value - an email that is already there.

You simply have to check the results of your query, if you don't have any errors then it was inserted, if you get this error, the email is already in use.

If I recall correctly, the error number is 1062 for a duplicate entry.

By doing this, you're avoiding an extra `SELECT`  query.

Answer (score 0):

Checking whether an email address is valid is incredibly complex; search stackoverflow for "verify email address" to get a feeling.

Thus, I don't think checking it with the same `if` clause is a good idea at all -- it even *reduces* the helpfulness of your error message by leaving your user in doubt about whether the email address is invalid or already there.

Comment: You're probably right, but i want to know this happend.

Comment: He's only doing very basic validation.  He's not trying to totally verify the e-mail is valid, but only make sure it's reasonable and no duplicates.  I see no problem with this.  He even used a built in PHP function for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using while loop and checking if the database has email entered or not.

following code.

```
function CheckEmail()
{
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $query = @mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='" . $email . "'");
     $a = mysql_num_rows($query);
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        if($row['email'] == $email){
            echo "Email you entered is already registered";
        }
     }
}
```